# AttributeError: 'Person' object has no attribute 'update' Django

Tags: python, django

Im having a problem with this query. All I want is to change the paid value if the paid is equals to `Yes` then it must be change into `Paid` and if paid is equals to `No` then it is `Unpaid`. The problem is Im having this kind of error `AttributeError: 'Person' object has no attribute 'update'`  . It is necessary to use `p.update`? to change the value from `Yes` to`Paid`?

> This is what I've been trying

```
  for p in Person.objects.filter(Q(paid = 'Yes')):
      p.update(paid="Paid")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either save each object.

```
for p in Person.objects.filter(Q(paid = 'Yes')):
      p.paid = "Paid"
      p.save()
```

OR

`update` method is available on `QuerySet`, hence you can use

```
Person.objects.filter(Q(paid = 'Yes')).update(paid="Paid")
```

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response, but I think it overrides all my paid value into "Paid", and also I have `No` value in my paid, if it is `No` then it will change to Unpaid and if it `Yes` it will turn to `Paid`. It is really possible?need help  thanks in advance

Comment: This will only update rows with `paid=Yes` value. It wont update `paid=No` rows. You can add another query to update `paid=No` rows. `Person.objects.filter(Q(paid = 'No')).update(paid="Unpaid")`
`

Comment: thanks for your response but can you check this, the result keeps override my data to `Paid` even though I have a  `No` in my paid . I just want to change the value from Yes to Paid but the problem is it overrides the data from No to Paid   `for p in Person.objects.filter(Q(paid='Yes')):
            p.paid = "Paid"
            rpts_paid.append(p.paid)`   [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLG7q.png)